# DbVisualizer cannot connect to PostgreSQL database without authentication

Tags: postgresql, dbvisualizer

I have a local PostgreSQL database that does not require authentication, but I cannot connect it through DbVisualizer when I leave 'Authentication' fields (Database Userid, Database Password) empty.

It shows the following error in **Connection Message**

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

Details:
   Type: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
   SQL State: 28000
```

DbVisualizer version is 9.5.6

Comment: That's right, because you need a user name to connect. Just enter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) pointed out, I did need the username after all. By default it's 'postgres'.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, "WHERE" do you enter it.

Comment: Under **Authentication** in `Database Userid` and `Database Password`. The third screen after "New Connection Wizard" in this  [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEqO9CAYgRU)